# How do I get image slider images not to stretch but keep positioning of captions?

Tags: css, wordpress

Here is the website I'm working on:

I can get the image not to stretch by removing height: 481px; but then I lose the caption and squares below the image and it moves around if the images are different heights. I've tried messing around with positioning, but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Do you mean that the images are being stretched out of dimensions to fill the width of the screen? Then you can take another approuch by NOT using images (<img>) but by using an HTML container (div, li, whatever) and set the background image through CSS (use a wide image!) that way the image can be positioned in the middle of the container..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can solve this.

A cleaner solution, as @Sven pointed out, would be to use the tag `<div>` instead of `<img>` and use the images as `background` for the div.

Or,

you can use the CCS clip property to crop all your images to the same size, while maintaining their original proportions:

```
img {clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px)}
```

*(check this link for documentation on clip:* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp*)*

The fastest solution for you at this point however (the one that needs less changes on your actual code) might be to use the absolute positioning, only, instead applying it to the div `.text-box` apply it to his parent `.slider-cont-wrapper`.:

```
.slider-cont-wrapper {position:absolute; top:100px; right:100px}
```

*(change `top:` and `right:` to measures that suit your layout)*

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if images don't have the same proportion, no matter what you do, you'll never get different image sizes fit perfectly in the same spot. so, what do you want?